# When I post comments on same object from my fan pages error: (#368) security check is required to proceed

Tags: facebook

When I post comments on same object from my fan pages (more than two pages I have) with graph api I get this **error: (#368) security check is required to proceed**, after second page (second access token)

**NOTE**: This happens even if the comments are not the same

[image: error: (#368) security check is required to proceed]

Comment: So you are trying to comment on the same post, "as" two of your pages, in quick succession? Facebook will probably think this might be spam then.

Comment: What is the ideal time interval to do this?